# How to deploy a Django and React project on the same Ubuntu 18.04 server using gunicorn and nginx?

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx, web-deployment, gunicorn

I have a Django project that I have already successfully deployed on my Ubuntu 18.04 server via gunicorn and nginx using this tutorial.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

The project uses Django Rest Framework and I'm able to access it's endpoints via a web browser. However, I would also like to deploy a separate react project on the same server, so that it can send http requests to the Django app and display data received from the REST API. How can I go about doing this?

Here is my current `gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/my_project/coffeebrewer
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/my_project/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/my_project/coffeebrewer/coffeebrewer.sock coffeebrewer.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And here are my current nginx configurations

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my_ipv6_address;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
       root root /home/ubuntu/my_project/coffeebrewer;

    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you **try it locally first as a production mode** by installing `whitenoise django package` and in your `settings.py` file add this line `SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = None`

From there, you can navigate forward